# How to programmatically make a TreeView visible

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to make a TreeView visible programmatically. The TreeView is empty.

I tried to call TreeView.reveal with a dummy TreeNode but it remains not visible.
The only other method available on TreeView is "dispose".
I don't see how I can have access to the "container" of this treeview as it is created using vscode.window.createTreeView(...).
I searched on vscode.window API but not found anything related to my purpose.

How can I reveal/make the TreeView visible programmatically?

```
fakeNode = new TreeNode("dummyType", "dummyLabel", "dummyStatus", vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.Expanded);
myTreeView.reveal(fakeNode); 
expect(myTreeView.visible).to.be.true
```

Comment: Can you share your code please, for better clarity

Comment: let fakeNode = new TreeNode("dummyType", "dummyLabel", "dummyStatus", vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.Expanded);

myTreeView.reveal(fakeNode);

expect(myTreeView.visible).to.be.true;

Answer (score 1):

it is currently not possible.
See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90005 for a feature request. You can upvote the github issue to increase the probability to have it possible one day.